# I wanted to know if this was incorrect. Nesting spans inside a heading tag

Tags: html, nested

I want to do this "? Question of life ?" with my code. I was having trouble figuring out a way to do this. Until I thought to nest the "?" in span tags inside the h1 tag for the text. It worked. However, I just want to know if this is the right way to achieve this goal or if there is a more of an official way. I don't want to pick up any wrong habits as i'm learning to code. This is the code below:

```
        <h1>
          <span class="qm" id="left-qm">?</span>
          Questions of life 
          <span class="qm" id="right-qm">?</span> 
        </h1>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with that code

Comment: @j08691 Thank you

Comment: If you need an `id` for one letter, this is the best way. But if your goal was different - it's redundancy, common but still wrong. Simple `<h1>? Question of life ?</h1>` didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

**Another approach for adding content before and after is  using `::before` & `::after` pseudo Element .**

This is how it works;

```css
h1::before,
h1::after {
  content: '?'
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Questions of life
</h1>
```

**Checkout All [pseudo-element](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)**